# How to prevent service stop when onTaskRemoved is calles?

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have a problem with music `Service` being stopped after "Swipe to exit" being performed on recent apps list in ICS. Service was started with `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` and it is automatically restarted after few seconds, but I want to prevent the stop at all.

"Swipe to exit" behaviour is generally unknown and I base my whole knowledge on this [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/what-actually-happens-when-you-swipe-an-app-out-of-the-recent-apps-list).
It contains comments from one of Google employees:

> [W]hat specifically happens when you swipe away a recent task is it: (1) kills any background or empty processes of the application (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle for what this means), and (2) uses the new http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent) API to tell any services of the application about the task being removed so it can do whatever it thinks is appropriate.

and

> Actually, removing an entry in recent tasks will kill any background processes that exist for the process. It won't directly causes services to stop, however there is an API for them to find out the task was removed to decide if they want this to mean they should stop. This is so that removing say the recent task of an e-mail app won't cause it to stop checking for e-mail.
>   If you really want to completely stop an app, you can long press on recent tasks to go to app info, and hit force stop there. For stop is a complete kill of the app -- all processes are killed, all services stopped, all notifications removed, all alarms removed, etc. The app is not allowed to launch again until explicitly requested.

According to second comment, my `Service` should be able to decide for itself what it wants to do - instead it is stopped without any action from me and gets restarted later.

Any ideas what to do with it? Using `START_STICKY` works exactly the same...

Answer (score 1):

Put your Service in [foreground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29). Note that you will have to display an ongoing Notification while the Service is running in foreground.

Comment: I am not sure how is that possible, but putting Service in foreground didn't prevent it from getting stopped, however it is not being restarted later...

Comment: Could you paste your code somewhere? I'm running fine with this method. You can also test music players which are using a foreground service (incl. the ongoing notification) which is not stopped after the player is "swiped to exit".

Comment: This may no longer work in KitKat due to a bug with foreground services causing the app to get killed anyways.